# how to sort events in full calendar with json property irrespective srart time and duration?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to sort events with my json property called "displayOrder". but not on start time. 
I have applied eventOrder:"displayOrder"  still not sorting based on given input

this means event one should appear first.
here is json

{
    "title": "Event two",
    "start": "2015-10-01T10:30:00-05:00",
    "end": "2015-10-02T17:30:00-05:00",
    "displayOrder":"2",
    "bookingsAvailable":true,
    "description":"We can add description in JSON"

},
  {
    "title": "Event one",
    "start": "2015-10-01T11:30:00-05:00",
    "end": "2015-10-01T17:30:00-05:00",
    "displayOrder":"1"
  }

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OrwH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {
     return compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs)|| //  events with display order
        seg1.displayOrder -seg2.displayOrder || // earlier events go first
        seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
        seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay  // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will requrie to modify `compareSlotSegs(seg1, seg2)` inside fullcalendar.js

```
   function compareSlotSegs(seg1, seg2) {
            return seg1.originalStart - seg2.originalStart || // earlier start time goes first
                    (seg2.originalEnd - seg2.originalStart) - (seg1.originalEnd - seg1.originalStart) || 
                    (seg1.event.displayOrder|| '').localeCompare(seg2.event.displayOrder); 
        }
```